# Laravel 5.0 white screen without logs?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I try everything to fix it:

```
-php artisan clear-compiled
-php artisan optimize
-composer update
-sudo chown -R :www-data /var/www/laravel
-sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/app/storage
```

When i create a new project with composer (create project) laravel works, the problem is not in ngninx, permissions, debian, etc.
Is in my project but laravel dont create any logs. When i install my project local it works too.i restart all services too.

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 geotel www-data   4096 Aug  4 22:19 app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 geotel www-data   1635 Aug  4 22:19 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  2 geotel www-data   4096 Aug  4 22:19 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--  1 geotel www-data    939 Aug  4 22:19 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 geotel www-data 116113 Aug  4 22:22 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 geotel www-data   4096 Aug  4 22:19 config
drwxr-xr-x  4 geotel www-data   4096 Aug  4 22:19 database
-rw-r--r--  1 geotel www-data    503 Aug  4 22:19 gulpfile.js
-rw-r--r--  1 geotel www-data     79 Aug  4 22:19 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 geotel www-data     87 Aug  4 22:19 phpspec.yml
-rw-r--r--  1 geotel www-data    729 Aug  4 22:19 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x  3 geotel www-data   4096 Aug  4 22:19 public
-rw-r--r--  1 geotel www-data   1724 Aug  4 22:19 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x  5 geotel www-data   4096 Aug  4 22:19 resources
-rw-r--r--  1 geotel www-data    561 Aug  4 22:19 server.php
drwxrwxrwx  5 geotel www-data   4096 Aug  4 22:19 storage
drwxr-xr-x  2 geotel www-data   4096 Aug  4 22:19 tests
drwxrwxr-x 32 geotel www-data   4096 Aug  4 22:26 vendor
```

with this permissions and is not working

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: Laravel 5.0 and debian 7.0

Comment: did you make any modification in `app\Exception\Handler.php` ?

Comment: check your ngninx log. may be you need to enable mod_rewrite openssh. Are you using homestead?

Comment: I am using a remote server, in local it works the same repo.

Answer (score 0):

set `APP_ENV=local` in `.env`,

set `APP_DEBUG=true` in `.env`

Make sure that `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG'),` written in `/config/app.php`

Allow recursive 777 permission to `/vendor` and `/storage` folder.

Comment: No need of 777 permission. Just `sudo chown -R www-data /vendor /storage` is best practice

Comment: just try `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` on your controller,